# one to many join - taking only the last one on the many part

Tags: entity-framework, join, max

I'm quite a newbie in EF, so I'm sorry if my question has been answered before.. I just can't figure out the syntax..

I have two entities, `Category` & `Product`, where one category has many products.

I want to get all categories, with only their latest product (it has a date property named timestamp)

I have no idea how to do that. :-/

If possible I'd like to know the syntax of the two ways to write it, both the **sql-like** syntax, and the **C# like** syntax, *e.g.*:

```
ctx.Categories.Include("Products").ToList() 

from c in ctx.Categories.Include("Products")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the SQL-like way:

```
var categories =
        from p in products
        group p by p.Category into g
        select new { Category = g.TheKey, LatestProduct = g.Max(p => p.TimeStamp) };
```

This is the Lambda-way (warning, untested):

```
var categories = products.GroupBy(p => p.Category)
                         .Select(g => new { Category = g.TheKey, 
                                            LatestProduct = g.Max(p => p.TimeStamp)});
```

A note on `Categories.Include("Products")`, you don't need this in your example. You use "Include" for eager-loading, so that for example if you had a list of Categories returned from EF, when you do Categories.Product you will get the associated product.

But all you require is a list of categories, and a single product for each one - which is already returned in the above LINQ query, so no need for Include.

Comment: Thanks! However, turns out I actually need something a bit different - I am working with Ria Services, so my method has to return IQueriable<Cateogry> and what you're returning here is an anonymous type (which is very restrictive to begin with - you can't really return that type from a method..) Can u plz supply me with a method that returns a list of categories, and for each category, the Products property would only contain the latest product? And while we're on the subject - is this the way to go? or should I add another Property to the Category? Thanks!

Comment: My answer was just an example for how to write the query, obviously you need to apply that to whatever scenario you have. :) Just change the projection from an anonymous type to the Category: `select new Category { Product = g.Max(p => p.TimeStamp) };`

Comment: and returning an IQueryable is a totally different beast. what's the point of returning an IQueryable list of Categories if you have already filtered/max'd the products? If you're returning an IQueryable, you should just return db.Categories (that's it), and the above code should be done where you want to project the IQueryable to a concrete collection - such as a service layer.

Comment: Are you familiar with WcfRiaServices (it's for silverlight)? u have to return IQueriable by default. It doesn't really return that - it's a shortcut to allow u to add filters on the client side. Just to make sure, if i want to put the selected product into the products property (there is no product property ofcourse), how would i do that? again, thank you very much :)

Comment: I don't have much knowledge in WCF RIA/SL, i focus on ASP.NET :) Okay so a "Category" object doesn't have a "Product" property? Then either add it to the Category object, or return some other object which does have it.

Comment: That is what I'm going to do, but again, my EF knowledge is horrible, so I'm just wondering how can I put the product into the Products property of Category. It's probably very very simple and I am going to buy a book about EF (do u have any recommandations btw?) but if u could show me the syntax for that it would be great :)

Comment: Im confused by what your issue is. can you not do this: `select new Category { Product = g.Max(p => p.TimeStamp) };` ? That will assign the latest product (by timestamp) to the 'Product' property of the 'Category' (assuming a Category entity has a Product property). As i said in my first comment above.

Comment: WRT books - i'm reading "Programming Entity Framework Second Edition" by Julia Lerman at the moment. Very good, extreme detail (914 pages)

Comment: the category has a productS property, not product (plural).

Comment: Right. In that case, something like this should work: `select new Category { Products = { new { g.Max(p => p.TimeStamp) } } };` This is not a EF/LINQ thing. You have a property called "Products" (IEnumerable<Product>, ICollection<Product>, etc), you need to add a single "Product" to the collection.